# Determining if a UTC time is within DST

Tags: c#, date, time, timezone

In C#, given a UTC time, how can I determine whether this falls within DST in Houston, Texas, US?

```
var utcDateTime = new DateTime(2013,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc);


//bool fallsWithinDstInAmerica = ...?
```

Comment: What do you mean by "falls within DST in Houston"?

Comment: Knowing that the difference is 6 hours? You can subtract them and check if you have a negative value then does not fall within it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the appropriate [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) for Texas, then use [`IsDaylightSavingTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460642.aspx).

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Don't be fooled by the "standard" part - this is Central Time
        var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
        var winter = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var summer = new DateTime(2013, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        Console.WriteLine(zone.IsDaylightSavingTime(winter)); // False
        Console.WriteLine(zone.IsDaylightSavingTime(summer)); // True
    }
}
```

Or using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), you can find the amount of daylight saving, and compare it with an offset of 0:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Chicago"];
        var winter = Instant.FromUtc(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0);
        var summer = Instant.FromUtc(2013, 6, 1, 0, 0);

        Console.WriteLine(zone.GetZoneInterval(winter).Savings); // +00
        Console.WriteLine(zone.GetZoneInterval(summer).Savings); // +01
        Console.WriteLine(zone.GetZoneInterval(winter).Savings != Offset.Zero); // False
        Console.WriteLine(zone.GetZoneInterval(summer).Savings != Offset.Zero); // True
    }
}
```